# How to get objects independently on text case

Tags: java, android, string, parse-platform, android-search

I've added search to my code and now am I wondering about one thing.

I'm using Parse.com's method:

```
query.whereContains("my_strings_from_Parse", text_from_EditText.toLowerCase())
```

I've made the text from EditText to lower-case bur right now do i need to make the strings from Parse.com lower-case.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String query = intent.getStringExtra("query");
ParseQuery<Animal> squery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
squery.whereContains("animal", query.toLowerCase()); //I need to make content of                                                                                                                                                                                                           //"animal"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with the case insensitive modifier, like stated [here](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> `public ParseQuery<T> whereMatches(String key,
>                                     String regex,
>                                     String modifiers)`
>
> Add a regular expression constraint for finding string values that match the
>   provided regular expression. This may be slow for large datasets.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> `key` - The key that the string to match is stored in.
>   `regex` - The regular expression pattern to match.
>   `modifiers` - Any of the following supported PCRE modifiers:
>       `i` - Case insensitive search
>       `m` - Search across multiple lines of input
>
> **Returns**:
>   Returns the query, so you can chain this call.

Comment: or go onto parse.com and cleanse your data. i.e query the data (from the webapp), change it all to lowercase and update all your rows. (This is a one time cleanse; if you are using 3rd party data that updates on it's own you will need @a.bertucci's solution)

Comment: Thank you both for helpful answers. Now am I trying the suggestion by a.bertuci. Question: how sould i define the last field when i want to use "i"? After that will i also try  @Blundell 's answer and find out, what is batter. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but ive figured it out. just used "i" of course, not i only. Thanks a lot